# Arrays Object with Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script

```
for(var i=0; i<sheet.getMaxColumns(); i++){
   params[i] = e.values[i]; 
  }

for(var z=0; z<paramsInfo.length; z++){
    var paramsInfoCheck = paramsInfo[z];
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(paramsInfoCheck.name);
    template[paramsInfoCheck.name] = params[paramsInfoCheck.number];
    template.recorded = params[35];

    if((params[paramsInfoCheck.number] < paramsInfoCheck.min) || (params[paramsInfoCheck.number] > paramsInfoCheck.max)){

      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,
    "F2 UPW 30K Parameter Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent() + spreadsheetlink});
    }

  }
```

The code that I have above is linked to an array of objects. I was wondering instead of using manual condition formatting where I have to apply to all my column(I have 50+ columns), is there any way that I can apply it in the IF statement. The cell will change color if the values obtained is out of a range. I'm using an onFormSubmit trigger event. T

Comment: I find hard to understand what is the expected behavior you are looking for. Could you clarify what is what you want to accomplish?
Also if you are able, could you provide a example sheet and the whole code?

Comment: @Raserhin - As of this moment, I am adding condition formatting manual to 50+ columns of data. I was wondering if by using an IF statement, is adding a conditional formatting by changing a cell color possible? Meaning to say, within that IF statement, I add a command where the cell color changes if the IF statement occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to make condition formatting on your Spreadsheet you can either [do that through the UI](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Or in Apps Script, if you do it in Apps Script you can of course make a solution like yours, being iterative, or you could try to use [`newConditionalFormatRule()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app.html#newconditionalformatrule)

From the official documentation

```
// Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in range A1:B3 to turn red
// if they contain a number between 1 and 10.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B3');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenNumberBetween(1, 10)
    .setBackgroundColor("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

Of course you can put more work in the conditional format you want to implement, take a look at all the options you can implement in [the `ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder.html)

Comment: Got it on this. I tried and it work but however, I'm having difficulties to link my value back to the original cell that it was retrieved from. As you can see in my code, I assigned ``e.values`` into ``params``, then this params is used to check for the value if its out of range. At this point, I am unsure of how to link that value back to the column/row that I retrieved from.

Comment: Sincerely I would need a better example of what you are trying to do. Could you please link a sample spreadsheet with clear instructions on what you want?
In your code I don't see any reference to the formatting of the cells so I don't know  what you mean with `IF` statement. Do you mean the Sheets formula?